# dialog box memory leak or stubborn GC?

Tags: android

When I load up my app, It takes around 3Mb of RAM. I have an `ImageButton` on my first activity which calls the function `showRecords`, which displays a dialog box.

Once the dialog box is opened, it can be closed by clicking outside of the box (which will call the `dismiss()` method). The problem I am having is that after the dialog box has been closed, the amount of RAM used by my application does not return to its previous state (it can remain over a Mb more If I include another stuff in the dialog - but the example retains around 2-300kb)

```
 public void showRecords(View v){    
    Dialog recordDialog = new Dialog(this);
    recordDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    recordDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    recordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.record);
    recordDialog.show();
}
```

The record.xml file has an image background, and another ImageView with a picture.

I have tried using MAT, and can see no Dialog objects in memory. I also have been using DDMS to perform garbage collections, but the RAM value never returns to what I would expect.

Is something binding to the activity? or is the GC just refusing the reclaim the memory?

As this is my first activity, it remains alive throughout and doesn't seem to close if I need more heap space  (for some reason). Therefore I'm quite interested in reclaiming a Mb of memory when it is not needed.

EDIT - record.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"         
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/recordspage"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is in `R.layout.record`? "doesn't seem to close if I need more heap space (for some reason)" -- that's normal behavior, activities do not automatically close due to low heap space (despite hints in the documentation to the contrary).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that was normal behaviour. Thanks for clearing that up. I will add record.xml to my question. I seem to lose some memory even without setting the contentView though.

Comment: Well, some of the memory will be `@drawable/recordspage` and `@drawable/background`, as drawable resources are held onto even if they are not being referenced presently, IIRC. "Is something binding to the activity?" -- if you BACK-button out of the activity, it should no longer show up in MAT. You might also use MAT to sort by biggest memory culprits, and examine it before and after launching the dialog.

Comment: I have tested creating a duplicate of my activity, launching my dialog in the second activity and going back to the first activity. The 2nd does not show up in MAT. I can't find any large amount of memory being used in MAT, I assume this is because bitmaps do not show up. I seem to have around 1.4Mb still remaining from the 2nd activity. Surely they should be removed at this point? Or is the GC so clever that it knows the first activity might like to use these resources at some point. Either way, is there any way I can force the GC to not keep these drawables? perhaps by using recycle.

Comment: "I assume this is because bitmaps do not show up" -- they should on Android 3.0+. In earlier versions of Android, bitmap memory is not reported by MAT. " Either way, is there any way I can force the GC to not keep these drawables?" -- not that I am aware of, if you wish to use them as resources. Bitmaps you load yourself from files or teh Internets you would `recycle()`. You don't have the `Bitmap` objects for the resources, though.

Comment: I can set the background and imageView programatically in the showRecord function and override the dismiss method on the dialog to recycle them perhaps? is there a better way

Comment: I'm testing it out on my phone with is running 2.3.3 I will try it out on an emulator

Comment: I just want to say thanks CommonsWare. You've helped me understand some things. I believe the key issue was, as you correctly pointed out, that the drawable resources were being kept in memory.

Comment: Interesting...when running android 3.0 the memory is freed as soon as the dialog box closes. I guess I must just be sure to Recycle everything that I've finished with!

Comment: They may have gotten smarter about dealing with resource memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that the analysis is out of the way... :-)

Bitmap resources take a hunk of heap space, because in memory they are held in their raw uncompressed format, compared to the PNG or JPEG you probably started with.

I notice that you are setting a background on a `LinearLayout`. That certainly works, but bitmap backgrounds are perhaps the biggest memory hogs, just due to their size. You might consider going with a flat color, a `ShapeDrawable`, or something that is less heap-intensive, if you are concerned about the space. This is particularly true for a dialog box, which is usually on the screen for mere moments.